# firebase realtime database rules: read,write = true. Can someone who will use my app hack my firebase account?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have developed an app which uses Firebase Realtime Database and want to publish it in google play store. I set database rules as read:true; write:true.

I don't care much about my database. It has not so much important data. I think nobody will even care about accessing my database and changing it.
I think even if some hacker writes some data in my database without using my app, I will be able to see it in my console.

My only concern is: can someone hack my whole firebase account just because I set the realtime database read and write rules true ?
To rephrase this question, does setting realtime database public put only database at risk or can it put my whole firebase account at risk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security rules only deal with direct access to the database.  They have nothing to do with anything else about your app or any Google account.  You will just be on the hook for all the billing (all the reads and writes) for that database, regardless of where the access comes from.

Comment: thanks. can someone use my realtime database in their work whatever it may be. I am asking this because otherwise why would someone "read or write" in my database for no reason other than just to make my billing high.

Comment: Yes they can do whatever **they** want in your database with these rules, which may not be in line with what you want. Even in those case you will be responsible for charges resulting from their operations, since **you** chose to publish an app with these rules.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks. I am using basic FREE plan(spark plan) of firebase. In the usage tab of realtime database, limits are given for different things.I think my app can't exceed these limits. If some malicious user used my database to these given limits then do I need to pay money to firebase ?

Comment: There is never any billing for projects on the Spark plan.